# Can't use Express to send data back to client more than once

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, heroku

In my app, I send a post request to the server with data containing a CSV file:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url:"/",
  data: JSON.stringify({fileData:My_CSV_FILE}),
  success: function(csvJson) {
    console.log('in the done block!');
    //can use csvJson in this handler
   });
});
```

Note: I'm posting to the home route, and I am able to get a response with the data converted from the server. The problem is that whether I run on localhost or Heroku, I am only able to trigger the POST request once, then I have to restart the server (even if I refresh the page). So I know the issue is with my route somewhere:

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE FULL SERVER FILE**:

```
    'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;

var converter = new Converter({});
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '300kb'}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

app.post('/',function(req,res) {
  var csvFile = (req.body.fileData);
  converter.fromString(csvFile, function(err, result) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log(result);
      res.json(result);
    }else {
      res.json({error: 'Could not convert'});
    }
  })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I'm using Express 4. Again, everything works, but only once. When I run Heroku logs, or check the console on localhost I get:

```
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

But I don't understand how I'm re-setting them.
If wanting to run on localhost, here is a link to the projects github: https://github.com/qctimes/calendar_export

Comment: There's probably more code you're not showing us, for instance where is the csvtojson middleware included? Somehow you're sending headers after you've started rendering.

Comment: @adeneo I updated the contents to include the full file and link to the project

Comment: I can't really spot any errors? The error is a classic, and as I noted above it means you're trying to set headers after they are sent, and you've started outputting content. Could possibly be that the `fromString` callback runs multiple times or something like that? Try just replacing `res.json()` with `res.send()` and see what happens

Comment: @adeneo no dice.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `converter` instantiation to be done inside the `app.post` callback method. This way it will instantiate a new object at every request.

This is is how your code should be:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '300kb'}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

app.post('/',function(req,res) {
  var csvFile = (req.body.fileData);
  var converter = new Converter({}); // instantiation is done here
  converter.fromString(csvFile, function(err, result) {   

    if(!err) {
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }else {
      res.send({error: 'Could not convert'});
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```